# Calculate pixel and area from PNG or Geotiff to measure area under NDVI

Tags: qgis, leaflet, software-recommendations, ndvi

We have built an Application that generates NDVI Imagery using API. 
What we are trying to achieve is to let users have an option to understand what areas of his/her farm have good and bad NDVI.NDVI images are always color-coded and for the farmer is difficult to measure exactly how much area is good, moderate, and bad.

We have tried few leaflet plugins and some image pixel detectors but they don't work.

Current App:
[![Current App][1]][1]

**Try to Achieve**
Now we want to calculate are for each/range pixel like the image below:
[image: Auto calculate area from Pixel]

We get those NDVI images into PNG or Geotiff.

What is the best way to achieve it?is there some function or tool which we can use and integrate into our web app for the same?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site.  Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that.  Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming I understand your question correctly, I hand you a quick solution for QGIS:

You can use the GRASS-Tool *r.reclass* in QGIS or directly in GRASS to reclassify your current values to nominal or ordinal classes and then use GDAL *Polygonize* to convert this into a vector dataset, for which you could easily calculate areas etc. You could then convert this back into a raster dataset, which I would not recommend though.

This process could easily be scripted and possibly also be integrated into your app.